# using export_fig with Matlab2016b

Tags: matlab, export, fig

I'm trying to use export_fig (latest version altmany-export_fig-5ad44c4) with Matlab2016b (Windows10, 64 bit, gs9.20). Settings of my graphics card are given below.

```
plot(cos(linspace(0, 7, 1000)));
export_fig('test1.png','test1.pdf')
print('test2.pdf','-dpdf')
```

The png-file is generated but the pdf-file contains only a gray box. I don't get any error message from export_fig. The native Matlab print command produces a correct pdf-file which has a lot of white space around the plot. To get rid of it I'd like to use export_fig.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Cheers

Heiner

---

**opengl info**
Version: '4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151.1008'
Vendor: 'ATI Technologies Inc.'
Renderer: 'AMD RADEON HD 6450'
RendererDriverVersion: '15.201.1151.1008'
RendererDriverReleaseDate: '04-Nov-2015'
MaxTextureSize: 16384
Visual: 'Visual 0x08, (RGBA 32 bits (8 8 8 8), Z depth 16 bits, Hardware acceleration, Double buffer, Antialias    4 samples)'
Software: 'false'
HardwareSupportLevel: 'full'
SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 1
SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 1
SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 1
Extensions: {266×1 cell}
MaxFrameBufferSize: 16384

Comment: It may be very specific problem. Did you try different Matlabs or different export_fig versions?

Comment: I would recommend [submitting an issue to the developer](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues) rather than relying on SO for technical support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments; I contacted the developer also but thought that the Stack Overflow community might be also interested in a solution of the problem.